# Translation of idiom 1970s

Tags: tradução, português-europeu

My sentence about saying goodbye to a Portuguese family (1970s) for a novel in English is:

> She’s already anticipating the day when it will be time to say **"until we meet again"**.

I think the correct Portuguese expression for "until we meet again" might be "*até à próxima vez*".

Am I correct?  Is there some better way to say this in Portuguese?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean with: "She's already anticipating the day when it will be time to say 'until we meet again'". Could you rephrase it, or explain in a comment?

Comment: The character in my book is visiting a family in Portugal and thinking about the day she has to say goodbye or ‘until we meet again.’ The phrase in quotes needs to be in Portuguese.

Answer (score 2):

Someone familiar with the Portuguese spoken in Portugal in the seventies can give you a more precise answer, especially since there are so many possibilities here, but your translation is, apart from eventual contextual subtleties, correct - though, at least nowadays, one is likely to omit '*vez*': *Até a próxima*.

Comment: @Lambie Yeah, some nuance or fine distinction due to the broader context...